# How to get friends(s) to confirm for certain if they are attending or not?

Tags: friends, conflict-aversion, friend-groups

I think this is a fairly common situation. When trying to arrange something, some people don't like to commit so they say "maybe". This is a problem, because space may be limited or reservations may need to be made.

Here is an example. I would like to go to a concert. I asked a friend who said "he should be able to come". If he's not able or doesn't want to come, that's fine, I will ask someone else. I just want a straight answer. How can I get this?

It gets even more complicated when a group is involved. At college I invited a few friends (who didn't know each other) to join me at the pub. Two showed up. They had entirely opposite personalities that weren't really compatible and they didn't like each other. This is another reason I like to know in advance who is coming. Though I do feel a bit immature in this line of thinking?

I don't think this is the same as [How to get somebody's confirmation when they say "I'll check my schedule"?](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/24024/) because it focuses on people saying "I need to check my schedule". In my situation people say "maybe" or just keep asking for more details.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! We recently had a similar question: [How to get somebody's confirmation when they say “I'll check my schedule”?](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/24024/) - do the answers there work for your situation too too? If not, it'd be great to [edit] to add why those answers won't help (that way people don't suggest the same things again).

Comment: It seems like those answers provide a whole lot of analysis and the only thing they suggest doing is to ask the invitee to get back by a certain time. I'm not sure this works because mine are not saying "I will get back to you"

Comment: the answers are applicable, your friends mean exactly the same thing as this persons friends when they say maybe.

Comment: I suggested the other question because it seemed like the responses ("when can you let me know for sure", "so I'll assume yes/no if I don't hear by Tuesday", etc.) would work just as well as a response to a "maybe". What do you normally respond with when someone says "maybe"?